# Flutter How to implement Stack functionality in a function

Tags: flutter, dart

Im working on a language learning app where you see the german word at first and then after 2 seconds the translated word shows up (Im using an animated opacity for that). My problem is that I don't know how to implement that functionality after the button (buttonfunctionality2 in this case) has been pressed. Here's my Stack:

```
  double opacity2 = 0.0;

  changeOpacityFirst() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        opacity1 = opacity1 == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        opacity1 = opacity1 == 0.0 ? 0.0 : 0.0;
        changeOpacityFirst();
      });
    });
  }

  changeOpacitySecond() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        opacity2 = opacity2 == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 1.0;
        opacity2 = opacity2 == 0.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0;

        changeOpacitySecond();
      });
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Möchtest du das Quiz beenden?'),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Ja'),
                        onPressed: () =>
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, DrawerScreen.id),
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Nein'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                      ),
                    ]));
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 64.0, 8.0, 8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  BackButton(),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      AnimatedOpacity(
                        opacity: opacity1,
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            mydata[0][i.toString()],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 48.0,
                              fontFamily: "Circular",
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedOpacity(
                        opacity: opacity2,
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            mydata[2][i.toString()],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 48.0,
                              fontFamily: "Circular",
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: AbsorbPointer(
                  absorbing: disableAnswer,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        choicebutton1('a'),
                        choicebutton2('b'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When the screen pops up, the Stack works for the first pair of words. I created a function called nextquestion, which gets triggered after the button has been pressed. Does somenone have an idea on how to implement the desired funciotnality into the function nextquestion()? Here's the button and the function:

```
void buttonfunctionality2(String k) {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), nextquestion);
  }

  Widget choicebutton2(String k) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 10.0,
        horizontal: 20.0,
      ),
      child: MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () => buttonfunctionality2(k),
        child: Text(
          mydata[1][i.toString()][k],
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFFF3F2F8),
            fontFamily: "Roboto",
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
          maxLines: 1,
        ),
        color: btncolor[k],
        splashColor: Color.fromRGBO(250, 139, 134, 1),
        highlightColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 171, 147, 1),
        minWidth: 200.0,
        height: 45.0,
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
    );
  }







void nextquestion() {
    setState(() {
      if (j < 20) {
        i = random_array[j];
        j++;
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Resultpage(marks: marks),
        ));
      }
      btncolor["a"] = Color.fromRGBO(250, 139, 134, 1);
      btncolor["b"] = Color.fromRGBO(255, 171, 147, 1);
    });
  }
```

Here's the full code (please go to learningscreens folder -> learninghome_screen:

https://github.com/BeffJezos/sankofa_language_school.git

Comment: Please try to add as little code snippets as possible. And add only the necessary parts of it, along with comments to understand your code better.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't quite get your code snippets. I'm answering based on the gist of what I understood from your question.

> My problem is that I don't know how to implement that functionality after the button (buttonfunctionality2 in this case) has been pressed.

For this, you can use the `Visibility` widget along with `setState`.

> Does somenone have an idea on how to implement the desired funciotnality into the function nextquestion()?

Same needs to be done here.

To give you an example:

If you have a `Text` widget that you want to show or hide programmatically, wrap the `Text` widget with the `Visibility` widget.

```dart
bool _isVisible = false; //will not be shown at first

Visibility(
    visible: _isVisible,  //false now, so the child Text won't be visible
    child: Text('Text here'),
),
```

Now you need to show the `Text` widget programmatically (perhaps your nextquestion() function), simply call the setState:

```dart
void nextquestion() {
    setState( () {
        //anything else you'd like to change here
        _isVisible = !_isVisible;
    } );
}
```

As soon as the `nextquestion()` is executed, the `Text` widget will become visible in the layout.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Forst of all sorry that I asked the question in a bad way. I’ll try to get better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the code snipped that shows the stack, or better the functionality of it should be inside the next question function. I have 20 German words and 20 translated words in my json file. And I want to have the German word Fade away/translated word Fades in -> button press -> repeat process with new pair of words. I hope now it’s more clear.